# Update the content of the iphone application

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4

I have uploaded some application on the iTunes Connect and its status is "Ready for sale" but now require to change some content of the application on the iTunes Connect like support URL or marketing URL etc.

So its require to add the new version of the application or with in that version i can change the content and if possible then i have done as per it but content is not updated on the live means in the itunes but when i see the iTunes Connect i will find the updated content over there but in real anyone see the app on the App Store then they find the old content only.

So now what all are the steps i require to update the content.

Comment: Never realized it would be THAT difficult to read without punctuations. Have you read about **in app purchases ?**

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to add a new version in order to change the metadata. Just update itunesConnect and it will replicate to the app store. This might take a while.

Note that you can not change categories or keywords without resubmitting a new binary.

Answer (score 0):

Select the app icon on itunes and then view detail, and then edit your provided info